# I can't find a mistake in the function

Tags: c, function, while-loop, newline, fgets

I am writing analog linux comand cat by C but I can't find a mistake inside function, which must numerate non-empty strings.
I get: segmentation fault, when I used this function (the code below):

```
void output_opt1_file(char *name_file) // функция открывает файл и нумерует только не пустые строки
{
    FILE *f = fopen(name_file, "rt");

    if (f != NULL) {
        char *string;
        fgets(string, 100, f);
        int i = 1;
        while (fgets(string, 100, f) != NULL) {
            if (strlen(string) == 0) //if (string[0] == '\n')
            {
                printf("%s", string);//puts(string);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d%c", i, ' ');
                ++i;
                printf("%s", string);//puts(string);                    
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

I need help for seeking my mistake.

Comment: You are using uninitialized pointer string: char *string;. Where are you going to read records from the file?

Comment: `string` is just a pointer; it needs to point to some memory, e.g., `char string[100];`

Comment: Note that the 'real' `cat` command doesn't use `fgets()` to read data or `printf()` to write data because it has to process files that contain null bytes.  Null bytes confuse code using `fgets()`.  It probably uses `fread()` and `fwrite()` for reading and writing.

Comment: thank you for your help! Now it's working. But I can't find the solution with numeration of non-empty string.... I use the condition with length of string. If the length is equal 0 then the string prints ( stdin). I have tried puts(string), after I changed on printf.... but again I got all numerated strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong at least by two reasons.

The first one is that the pointer `string` is uninitialized.

```
char *string;
```

You need to declare a character array instead of the pointer like for example

```
char string[100];
```

The second problem is that this if statement

```
 if (strlen(string) == 0)
```

will never evaluate to logical true because the function `fgets` at least can read a new line character `'\n'` for an empty string from a text file.

Instead you could write

```
 if ( string[0] == '\n')
```

And this call before the while loop

```
    fgets(string, 100, f);
    int i = 1;
    while (fgets(string, 100, f) != NULL) {
```

skips the first record.

Pay attention to that in general a record in a file can be larger than or equal to `100` characters. For example if a record in a file contains exactly `99` characters plus the new line character `'\n'` then your function will consider this record as two records: the new line character of the record will be considered as a separated second empty record.

Comment: Vlad, earlier I used fgetc and I forgot to eliminate this string, I only changed... :(
and I had version with the first symbol, but I commented this variant... because I can't find the solution with pointer ))) Now, this part is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's working version:

```
void output_opt1_file(char *name_file)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(name_file, "rt");
    if (f != NULL) {
        char string[100];
        int i = 1;
        while (fgets(string, 100, f) != NULL) {
            if (string[0] == '\n')
            {
                printf("%s", string);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d%c", i, ' ');
                ++i;
                printf("%s", string);                    
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```